# c# sending mail from window form not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, email

I'm having some wierd behaviour in my WinForm application coded in c#.

in my: 
`private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Im calling my function:
`functions.sendStatusEmail();`

The weird thing is that, when I press the <kbd>Save</kbd> button then email send is not triggered. But if I close my application the mail is handle and sent.

Have I missed something or do one need to trigger som application event manually to have run the sendout.

( I tried using `client.SendAsync(mail,null);` then it triggerd at click but the mail was empty)

Thanks in advance

--
Edit: code expamples

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // checks if a ticket is active
    if (workingTicketId > 0)
    {
        // update ticket information
        functions.updateTicketInfo(workingTicketId, comboBoxPriority.SelectedIndex, 
                                    comboBoxStatus.SelectedIndex, textBoxComment.Text);

        // gives feedback
        labelFeedback.Text = "Updated";

        // updates the active ticket list
        populateActiveTicketList();

        // marks working ticket row in list
        dataGridActiveTicketList.Rows[workingGridIndex].Selected = true;

        // checks for change of ticket status
        if (comboBoxStatus.SelectedIndex != workingTicketStatus)
        {
            // checks if contact person exists
            if (labelContactPersonValue.Text.ToString() != "")
            {
                // sends email to contact person
                functions.sendStatusEmail(labelContactPersonValue.Text, comboBoxStatus.SelectedIndex, workingTicketId, textBoxDescription.Text);
            }

            // updates working ticket status
            workingTicketStatus = comboBoxStatus.SelectedIndex;
        }

    }
}
```

and the send email function:

```
// sends a status email to contact person   
// returns noting
public void sendStatusEmail(string email, int newStatus, int ticketId, string ticketText)
{
    // defines variables
    string emailSubject;
    string emailBody;


    // some exkluded mailcontent handling

    // sends mail
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("myFromEmail@hidden.com",email,emailSubject,emailBody);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailSMTP"]);

    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    client.Send(mail);

    // dispose
    mail.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Post the code of sendStatusEmail ()

Comment: ...and also the code of buttonSave_Click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot understand why it would not work. I used below function and it sends the email successfully:

```
public static bool SendEmail (string smtpServer, string fromAddress, string fromDisplayName,
    string toAddress, string subject, string contents, bool important) {

    MailAddress from = new MailAddress (fromAddress, fromDisplayName);
    MailPriority priority = important ? MailPriority.High : MailPriority.Normal;

    MailMessage m = new MailMessage {
        From = from,
        Subject = subject,
        Body = contents,
        Priority = priority,
        IsBodyHtml = false
    };

    MailAddress to = new MailAddress (toAddress);
    m.To.Add (to);

    SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient (smtpServer) { UseDefaultCredentials = false };

    c.Send (m);
    return true;
}
```

No offence but are you sure that it is closing the application which results in email being sent. Most of the times there is a delay between an email is sent and it is received because of the traffic on SMTP server. Try pressing that button and then wait for some time (3-4 minutes) and try refreshing your inbox during that time.

Comment: No offence taken, Im quite new to .net alltogheter, and my conclusions does not make sense to me, but I have tried waiting with no result.  The one thing is that when I close my application my desktop outlook gives the system icon of sending a mail. And then I recive it.  And when I dont close the application I get a error from Norton saying something in the terms mail could not be sent due to timeout or so.

Comment: Your desktop outlook has *nothing* to do with *sending* an email. Perhaps because you see the icon because you *receive* the email. To confirm, try closing the outlook and you should still be able to send emails. About Norton: Is it a message from Norton Anti-virus?

Comment: Yep its from the antivir but not the regular kind. Anyhow, I tried to run it from another box and it worked, So I guess it has something todo with the Norton on my box. Thank you for your efforts, and sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: I hear "It works on *my* machine" from developers but "doesn't work on developer's machine" is certainly a rare case. Good luck!

Comment: The only real difference between Hemant's code and asd81 is the lack of a call to MailMessage.Dispose... I also notice in the example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) the only call to Dispose is for the attachment, rather than the MailMessage.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the SendAsync didnt work because you called mail.dispose() after the Async call.
The right way to do it in async would be,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from@domain.com", "to@domain.com", "subj", "body");
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("SMTPHOST");
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    client.SendCompleted += new
    SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

    client.SendAsync(mail,mail);//send the mail object itself as argument to callback

}

private void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //Mail sending is cancelled
    }
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        //There is an error,e.Error will contain the exception
    }
    else
    {
        //Do any other success processing
    }

    ((MailMessage)e.UserState).Dispose();//Dispose
}
```